# Class implementations in interface dll?

Tags: c#, architecture, interface, class-design

my problem: Inside an application, all interfaces are declared inside an own dll(project "interfaces", for example).

Inside project interfaces, there are many class implementations, too.

Now I need one of this implemented classes inside another project and get a ring dependency because this project is also a reference in project interfaces.

So, what is the best way to get around this ring dependency? Could it be possible that this is a big mistake in the design of the application?

Schematic representation:

IBigInterface.cs (everything in one file):

```
interface ISomeInterfaceA
{
    void SomeFunctionA(ClassB x);    // ClassB from newProject.cs
    void SomeFunctionB();
}

//
// etc.
//
class ClassA
{
    //
    // Code
    //
}
```

newProject.cs (everything in one file):

```
class ClassB
{
    //
    // used in interfaces.dll
    //
}

class ClassC
{
    void SomeFunction(ClassA a)    // ClassA from IBigInterface.cs
    {
        //
        // do something
        //
    }
}
```

First thing that comes into my mind would be sth. like:

IBigInterface.cs:

```
interface ISomeInterfaceA
{
    void SomeFunctionA(IInterfaceB x);    // use interface instead of a class
    void SomeFunctionB();
}

interface IInterfaceB
{
    //
    // declarations
    //
}

class ClassA
{
    //
    // implementation
    //
}
```

newProject.cs:

```
class ClassB : IInterfaceB    // implementation of IInterfaceB
{
}

class ClassC
{
    void SomeFunction(ClassA a)
    {
        //
        // implementation
        //
    }
}
```

so that project newProject wouldn't be a reference in project interfaces anymore (although this means changes in the whole application).

P.S.: I inherited this application so the idea of implementing classes in an interface-project was not my idea :).
In General, I would create one file per class (so don't point to this :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there's nothing wrong with combining concrete classes and the interfaces they implement into a single assembly (though it would be a bit strange to call the project "interfaces").

Having said that, circular references are usually a sign that you've over-modularized your code: the parts causing the circular reference belong together and they should be merged into a single assembly.

Other times, a circular reference is just a sign that a class is in the wrong layer; the class  needs to be moved into another assembly altogether (usually out of a lower-level infrastructure assembly and into a higher-level assembly). For example, `ClassC` might really belong in another project that *references* the "interfaces" assembly.

Comment: "the parts causing the circular reference belong together" - I agree with you on the general part, but it can also be because a component that belongs in a top layer was placed in a bottom layer. I had the misfortune of taking over such code :( took me days to fix, and move components to the correct layers.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the reason why Java *requires* public definitions to be in their own files (but I think you get the concept here :)).

It's usually not good to mix pure interface and implementation (though there are cases where it could be useful), and it's definitely a troublemaker if you export those into DLLs.

A cyclic dependency means your projects are too coupled to be distinct. This is usually a symptom of bad design (*[big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)*-like). You should either work on removing that coupling or merge both projects together.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific project that, as you say, contains all your interfaces, why not introduce another project that contains "helper classes" such as `ClassA`? Then your interface DLL and the projects depending on the interface DLL could use the classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to factor out the classes and interfaces that are common to several projects into a "Common" assembly (or similar), which has no dependencies to the assemblies that reference it.

For example, a business entity such as `Product` does not have to know anything about how it is persisted to a database or fetched via a web service, but the service components that *do* things with `Product`, for example `IProductsRepository`, needs to know what a `Product` is. Thus the assembly (or namespace) where `IProductsRepository` is defined holds a reference to the assembly (or namespace) where `Product` lives, but not the other way around.